# How to make my text view clickable in order to generate Buttons dynamically in the same activity?

Tags: android, textview

```
final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setId(i);
            tv.setText(qs.getQuestions().get((i / 3) - 1).getType().toString());
            ll.addView(tv);
            String w = qs.getQuestions().get((i / 3) - 1).getOption().toString();
            String[] x = w.split(",");
            if ((tv.getId() == 3) && (tv.getText().toString() == "RadioButton")) {
                RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);
                for (int r = 0; r < x.length; r++) {
                    RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
                    rdbtn.setText(x[r]);
                    radiogroup.addView(rdbtn);
                    ll.addView(radiogroup);
                    setContentView(ll);
                }
            }
            if ((tv.getId() == 7) && (tv.getText().toString() == "DD")) {
                ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int q = 0; q < x.length; q++)
                    spinnerArray.add(x[q]);
                Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
                spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

                ll.addView(spinner);
                setContentView(ll);
            }
            if ((tv.getId() == 11) && (tv.getText().toString() == "chkbox")) {
                for (int p = 0; p < x.length; p++) {
                    CheckBox ch = new CheckBox(this);
                    ch.setText(x[p]);
                    ll.addView(ch);
                    setContentView(ll);
                }
            }
```

This is my code
I want to generate Radio Buttons , Check Boxes and Drop Down Boxes dynamically on Clicking the textView 
How to make my text view clickable in order to generate Buttons dynamically in the same activity?

Answer (score 0):

Use 
    tv.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        void onClick(View v){
            //code to generate buttons
        }
    });

also make clickable attribute to true in xml or setClickable(true) in java.

Comment: I am still not getting it

Comment: Have you problem in generating buttons or in making textview clickable?

Comment: I have problem in making the textview clickable . .

Comment: Let me see what you did.